# Ultrasonic sensor get distance with java

Tags: gpio, java, pi4j

I use this script http://devilqube.blogspot.nl/2013/02/using-ultrasonic-range-finder-with.html to get values from my ultrasonic sensor. When I run the code and print the distances it results in a lot zeros with sometimes 165.7 as value. Im sure the GPIO setup is correct. Can someone help me with solving this problem?

Comment: why java, what stops you from using `python`?

Comment: Im in a project group and our group has more experience with java so we dediced to use java.

Comment: Java is probably even worse than Python at this task.  Check that your target is a metre or so away from the sensor.  A common mistake is for the echo pulse to have finished before the software gets a chance to check it started.

Comment: The java code takes the difference in times and multiplies that by 165.7.  When the difference is 0 you get zeros,  When it's 1 you get 165.7.

Answer (score 1):

I have written some java classes to use ultrasonic sensor with one of my project. Here it is.

**PiJavaUltrasonic.java**

```
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.*;

//to control pwm pins
//pwm1 23,24 ; pwm0 1, 26
import com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio;
import com.pi4j.wiringpi.SoftPwm;

public class PiJavaUltrasonic{
    //bcm, GPIO_#
    private int PIN_ECHO,PIN_TRIG;
    private long REJECTION_START=1000,REJECTION_TIME=1000; //ns

    private GpioController gpio;//gpio controller ; using io.gpio
    private GpioPinDigitalOutput//gpio output pins; using io.gpio, digital pins
        pin_trig;
    private GpioPinDigitalInput
        pin_echo;

    public PiJavaUltrasonic(int ECHO, int TRIG, long REJ_START,long REJ_TIME){ //GPIO
        this.PIN_ECHO=ECHO;
        this.PIN_TRIG=TRIG;
        this.REJECTION_START=REJ_START; this.REJECTION_TIME=REJ_TIME;

        gpio=GpioFactory.getInstance();// create gpio controller , io.gpio

        //motor_1_left_en=gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_01, "motor_1_left_en", PinState.HIGH);
        pin_trig=gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.getPinByAddress(PIN_TRIG), "pin_trig", PinState.HIGH);//pin,tag,initial-state
        pin_trig.setShutdownOptions(true, PinState.LOW);

        pin_echo=gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.getPinByAddress(PIN_ECHO),PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN);//pin,tag,initial-state

    }

    public int getDistance() throws Exception{ //in milimeters
            int distance=0; long start_time, end_time,rejection_start=0,rejection_time=0;
            //Start ranging- trig should be in high state for 10us to generate ultrasonic signal
            //this will generate 8 cycle sonic burst.
            // produced signal would looks like, _|-----|
            pin_trig.low(); busyWaitMicros(2);
            pin_trig.high(); busyWaitMicros(10);
            pin_trig.low(); 

            //echo pin high time is propotional to the distance _|----|
            //distance calculation
            while(pin_echo.isLow()){ //wait until echo get high
                busyWaitNanos(1); //wait 1ns
                rejection_start++;
                if(rejection_start==REJECTION_START) return -1; //infinity
            }
            start_time=System.nanoTime();

            while(pin_echo.isHigh()){ //wait until echo get low
                busyWaitNanos(1); //wait 1ns
                rejection_time++;
                if(rejection_time==REJECTION_TIME) return -1; //infinity
            }
            end_time=System.nanoTime();

            distance=(int)((end_time-start_time)/5882.35294118); //distance in mm

    }

    public static void busyWaitMicros(long micros){
        long waitUntil = System.nanoTime() + (micros * 1_000);
        while(waitUntil > System.nanoTime()){
            ;
        }
    }

    public static void busyWaitNanos(long nanos){
        long waitUntil = System.nanoTime() + nanos;
        while(waitUntil > System.nanoTime()){
            ;
        }
    }

}
```

**Test_Ultrasonic.java**

```
public class Test_Ultrasonic{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        PiJavaUltrasonic sonic=new PiJavaUltrasonic(
            0,//ECO 11
            1,//TRIG 22
            1000,//REJECTION_START ; long
            23529411 //REJECTION_TIME ; long
        );
        System.out.println("Start");
        while(true){
            System.out.println("distance "+sonic.getDistance()+"mm");
            Thread.sleep(1000); //1s
        }
    }

}
```